# How do you get positional audio to work in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, audio, scenekit

I am having trouble getting positional audio to work in SceneKit. Starting with the SceneKit game template generated by Xcode I have added the following code to the end of the handleTap method:

```
let ship = scnView.scene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!  
if let source = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "art.scnassets/monoAudioTest.wav")  
{  
    source.volume = 1  
    source.isPositional = true  
    source.shouldStream = true  
    source.loops = true  
    source.load()  
    let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)  
    ship.addAudioPlayer(player)  
}  

ship.runAction(SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(0, 0, -10000), duration: 8))
```

The audio plays but the volume doesn't decrease as the jet moves away from the camera. Am I missing some steps or making some wrong assumptions?

Cross-posted to the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70538).

Comment: I just tried, but with a left-to-right move instead of near-to-far. I also used an MP3 instead of a WAV. I didn't hear any positional change either. I tried switching to SCNAction.playAction but that made no difference.

Comment: I had a similar experience to @HalMueller with positional audio in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get positional audio with `source.shouldStream = false`.

Comment: It seems totally ridiculous that that should work but it fixes my problem. Do you think that's a bug or just poorly documented?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, I've tried every configuration I can think of, the volume never changes as the node moves away. I've also tried various audio formats including .aif, .mp3 and .wav, no difference. I read in another post that .aif worked for someone, but no luck for me. Perhaps it has to do with the encoding used.

Comment: @AdamEisfeld Is your audio file mono? If the audio is stereo SceneKit will not position it.

Comment: As of now (in my experience), SceneKit positional audio does *technically* work -- but the sounds are way too quiet. I've set the max value of `1.0` for both `audioSource.volume` and `audioPlayer.audioNode?.engine?.mainMixerNode.outputVolume`. I've used a .wav file with maximized volume in mono format. I've set `audioSource.shouldStream = false`. The only other thing I can think to try is to turn DOWN the volume on all OTHER sounds in the game so the user turns UP the volume on the device, thus hearing positional sounds. Haven't tried that yet. Might be a bad solution, though.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by Jed Soane, and confirmed by Apple in a Radar, the issue was my audio file was stereo instead of mono. Only mono audio files will work for positional audio.