# SCNAudioSource isn't positional

Tags: ios, scenekit

My game can play sound successfully now by using the SCNAudioSource and SCNAction. For example:

```
let audioSource1 = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "Fire.mp3")!
audioSource1.isPositional = true
let play = SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource1, waitForCompletion: false)
audioNode.runAction(play)
```

But it seems that the isPositional attribute doesn't work at all, even after I artificially set the camera as the SCNView's audioListener.

I guess that the problem has something to do with the *scale*. For example, the volume of a sound will diminish 0.1 dB per meter. But since my game objects are so small and the camera moves so slowly, I cannot observe any distinct change of the volume by moving the camera away from the sound source. Is this correct?

How can I fix this problem?

SOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get positional audio to work in SceneKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555867/how-do-you-get-positional-audio-to-work-in-scenekit). Is your audio file mono? Does it stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my files mono solves the problem.